# Why do I get a black screen using exoplayer?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using ExoPlayer in my Android app project but I don't know why I get a black screen in my app. When I first run the appm I used `this` instead of `baseContext` and the video played very well.

But now I can only see a black screen. There is no problem with the resource.

```
    exoplayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(baseContext, 
    DefaultTrackSelector())

    val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(baseContext, "Exo")
    val mediaUri = Uri.parse("asset:///exerciselv2.mp4")
    val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource(mediaUri, 
    DefaultDataSourceFactory(baseContext, userAgent), 
    DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null)

    exoplayer?.prepare(mediaSource)
    exoplayer?.playWhenReady = true

    exoplayerView?.player = exoplayer
```

I can't get any error messages, just on views... Please, help me TT

Comment: If you put whole of class here, it will be easier that we can find out where is the problem.

Comment: Please, could you solve the problem? I have the same bug, it reproduces the audio but not the image of the video :(